# How to write multiple queries in a single function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I need to write a function in Postgresql where the function will return a table with three columns. These three columns will be populated from three different queries. **I want to know how to club these three queries in a single function.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ytd(MMYY character varying, MMYY1 character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(name character varying, ratio bigint, ratio1 bigint) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
RETURN query
SELECT col1 as name from t1, 
Select col2 as ratio from t2,
Select col3 as ratio1 from t3


END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION ydt2(MMYY character varying, MMYY1 character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Same parameter will be passed in each sql

Comment: Why don't you use JOIN if you have relation between these tables?

Comment: Tables are not related. How do I join three queries?

Comment: Then how could you tell which name goes with which ratio?

Comment: I want quer1 goes to name and so on...I am new in database..so i want to know is it possible to club multiple queries in single function?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the three table structures? Put the code in this way you could also susbstitute the `FUNCTION` with a `PROCEDURE` and make use of three output parameters.

Answer (score 3):

If the method of how you `JOIN` the three data-sets is irrelevant (and as you say they are unrelated), then merging the three data-sets should be quite trivial (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/05af0/5)).

This SQL (below) should exemplify with an example:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a1 INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE b (b1 INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE c (c1 INTEGER);

INSERT INTO a VALUES(11), (12);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(21), (22);
INSERT INTO c VALUES(31), (32);

WITH 
  aa AS (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS r, * FROM a),
  bb AS (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS r, * FROM b),
  cc AS (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS r, * FROM c)
SELECT r, a1, b1, c1
FROM aa
  JOIN bb
    USING (r)
  JOIN cc
    USING (r)
```